# Why Relu activity function make the input that is below zero to be zero as output?

Tags: deep-learning

Why the meaning of doing it that output zero when input is below 0. 
Is it a good way to calculate the gradient ? Or something else.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Relu activation function is designed to squash the value of it's output to 0 when it's input is below zero.

`RELU(x) = max(0, x)`

It's not to improve the calculation of gradient but more about sustaining the gradient value. Other activation functions that were precursors of relu like `sigmoid` or `tanh` (only ones that I know about) had the problem of saturation leading to vanishing or exploding gradient problem. Relu's do not have that in their positive direction.

[image: plot of RELU and it's comparison with softplus]

As you can see for this 2D plot, the blue function is unbounded in the positive side. The issue with relu's is that it's non-differentiable at origin implying that we cannot calculate it at that point but the sub-gradients do exist in both the positive and the negative direction.
An approximation to this is the analytic RELU ( the green function) given by `f(x) = ln(1 + exp(x))` which also has the advantage of not having the saturation issue in the positive side as well as the fact that it's differentiable throughout. You can read more about activation functions [here](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/)

Comment: Since for input which below zero, the correspond gradient is always zeos, which will lead to no refresh for them. What I want to know is why the gradient belong to the part below 0 is always zero. Is there any benefit for doing this ?

Comment: There are two reasons in my opinion. One is that it applies biological plausability and it gives it a linear form which results in faster conference.

Comment: Faster *convergence.

Comment: I know this is an old thread. But to anybody who visits this thread later than me: you might want to read the paper "A SIMPLE GEOMETRIC PROOF FOR THE BENEFIT OF
DEPTH IN RELU NETWORKS".  As my understanding, ReLU's nonlinearity successful is due to its ability to "slice" the hyper-surfaces that defines the classification margins.